# Should I be worried by these rhubarb leaves?

Tags: rhubarb

I have 3 rhubarbs in large pots that for the past 3 years have given a very nice crop. Usually the leaves are a nice consistent green colour but this year one of the plants has suddenly got yellow mottling (see picture) is this somthing I need to be aware of? I do feed them regularly and at the end of every winter the pot soil is refreshed by removing the top inch or so, string fresh compost in alongside blood fish and bone and chicken pellets.

[image: Rhubarb leaves]

Fertilizer info

[image]!

Comment: My first guess would be they need nitrogen fertilizer. Easy and cheap to do before looking for more sophisticated problems. How much N is in the fertilizers you are using?

Comment: Added a picture